# Netem does not show the correct parameter inserted

Tags: linux, tc, delay

I'm issuing the following [`tc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html) command

```
tc qdisc
```

in order to configure different queues in a computer. The problem is that when I configure two different queues (`htb` configuration) and I insert parameters with `netem` and I try to visualize them, the delay is always showing 274.9s (inserting delays such as 100ms, 200ms, etc).

Example:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:10 handle 10: netem delay 200ms loss 5%
```

Response to the command:

```
qdisc netem 10: dev eth1 parent 1:10 limit 1000 delay 274.9s  274.9s loss 5%
```

Comment: I don't get this behaviour with netem (I get 200.0ms displayed as expected). You should retry with recent enough iproute2 tools matching a recent kernel.

Comment: I tried it with the latest version of Raspbian (buster) and the latest stable version of iproute2 in debian (4.20.0-2) and I had the same result showing delay as 274.9s no matter which number of delay inserted. May be is a bug of the latest package?

Comment: was working on amd64 arch with Debian buster-backports' iproute2 (5.4.0~bpo10+1 <=> iproute2-ss191125) package and 5.5.4 (patched with Debian's patches). Not that it should matter that much. In very rare casess 32 bits userland and 64 bits kernel might have incompatibilities (but I heard about this only for xfrm and ipsec). Is everything 64 bits?